# How to use request scoped bean in a reactor framework async call?

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor, reactor, requestscope

Not able to use request scoped bean in a reactor code. Facing the below exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.eventProcessor': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton;
```

nested exception is `java.lang.IllegalStateException:`

```
No thread-bound request found: 
Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? 
If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request
```

Comment: please provide some code or example to help others to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.